# Acetic acid reaction sequence

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

Can anyone tell me where I am doing it wrong for the following reaction? [image]

In the first step, Br should be attached to the alpha carbon.

In second step, the bromide is replaced by cyanide.

I am able to get the third product that is final compound.

Comment: Heating a carboxylic acid often leads to decarboxylation. So decarboxylate your product from step 2 (well actually the product formed following acidification in step 3!)

Comment: @Leeser can you tell me the products formed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: $\alpha$-bromination
$$\ce{CH3-COOH + Br2/P -> Br-CH2-COOH}$$

Step 2: Nucleophilic Substitution by Sodium Cyanide
$$\ce{Br-CH2-COOH + NaCN -> NaBr + NC-CH2-COOH}$$

Step 3: Acid-catalyzed Conversion of Nitrile to Amide or Acid

(1) First hydration... $$\ce{NC-CH2-COOH + H2O -> H2N-CO-CH2-COOH}$$ 
(2) Further heating... $$\ce{H2N-CO-CH2-COOH -> HOOC-CH2-COOH + NH4+}$$

**Special Notes**

Be VERY CAREFUL with Step 2 as you are potentially forming $\ce{HCN}$ which could get everyone in the lab killed if you're not careful.

Comment: But @sixtytrees has made different products

Comment: @user123733 No, he only went step further with decarboxylation, without any good reason.

Answer (score -1):

There are two possibilities. You will have a two step reaction

NC-CH2COOH -> HOOC-CH2-COOH This is malonic acid. It can be further decarboxylated to

HOOC-CH2-COOH + H$^+$ + heat -> CO2 + CH3COOH

the final product is acetic acid.